'SymbolicTensor' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
I have been trying to implement Peephole LSTM using Tensorflow, and I am getting the error below
Error
below is my model and I am not sure why I cant get the input layer in my model summary
Model
and below is my Call method for PeepholeLSTM
Peephole LSTM class
It looks like I cannot pass symbolic Tensorflow object to range method but not sure how to avoid this. Appreciate your help

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please add your code as actual code in the question, images are bad.

tf.shape() returns a tensor.  I think you mean to do something like
for t in range(input.shape[1]):

